# How to dynamically change options for `dropdown_2` based on `dropdown_1` selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For example: if I choose `plant 2` or `plant 3` from `dropdown_1`, then `dropdown 2` options should change automatically to the `other option`.

Can anyone help-me please? I thank you in advance!

here's my DEMO

[Demo][1]

```
<select name="" id="dropdown_1">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="">plant 1</option>
  <option value="">plant 2</option>
  <option value="">plant 3</option>

</select>

<select name="" id="dropdown_2">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="">outside 1</option>
   <option value="">inside 1</option>
</select>
//other option is 
//outside 2/3
//inside 2/3


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/Tafreets/68k2pvg3/
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, every plant on the first select has its own options?

Comment: yes, it has own option

Comment: So suggest having a different select for every option above and toggle between them depending on the selected option. Do you use JQuery?

Comment: Where did you store your options? In a database or JSON file? Did you try to use jQuery or Ajax? Please explain and add more details. Please read about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: JSON file and selected go to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options. First option is to use change event on first dropdown then read the selected value, empty the 2nd dropdown and then have if/else or switch statement to add options to 2nd dropdown : [Demo](https://codepen.io/nik8singh/pen/LYmKbym?editors=1111)

```
$('#plantType').on('change', function() {
    var actionDrop = $("#location");
    actionDrop.empty();
    switch(this.value) {
      case 'plant1':
        actionDrop.append($('<option>', {value:'outside1', text:'outside 1'}));
        actionDrop.append($('<option>', {value:'inside1', text:'inside 1'}));
        break;
      case 'plant2':
        actionDrop.append($('<option>', {value:'outside2', text:'outside 2'}));
        actionDrop.append($('<option>', {value:'inside2', text:'inside 2'}));
        break;
    }
    
  });
```

Second option have separate dropdown elements. when user selects from first dropdown then show and hide dependent dropdowns based on the selection using javascript or Jquery : [Demo](https://codepen.io/nik8singh/pen/XWZpQqB)

```
$('#plantType').on('change', function() {
  $('.location').hide();
  if (this.value==="plant1"){
     $('#plant1Location').show()
  }else if(this.value==="plant2"){
    $('#plant2Location').show()
  }
});
```